# Find biggest and smallest array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the best way to compare two arrays.

Essentially I want to know the biggest and smallest array for further processing.  Here is my code for doing so thus far:

```
merge: function(arrOne, arrTwo) {

   if(arrOne == null || arrTwo == null) throw new Error();

    var bigArr = arrOne.length > arrTwo.length ? arrOne : arrTwo,
        smallArr = bigArr.length == arrOne.length ? arrTwo : arrOne;

    console.log(bigArr);
    console.log(smallArr);

}
```

While this works, I am guessing there has to be an easier and more efficient way of doing this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code works; I would use a single IF, though, unless you have specific restrictions that you didn't tell us

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your current implementation. Comparing lengths is not inefficient in any way.

Comment: @JanDvorak How would you do this with a single `if`??

Comment: Yes, a single `if` will make it slightly more efficient but not much.

Comment: @techfoobar it will make it much more readable, OTOH

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, thats true. A simple if will be more readable any day than a single line ternary.

Comment: Are you just saying to convert this to a single `if else` rather than a ternary??

Comment: @JanDvorak - A single `if` will also decrease the number of comparisons by 1, making it *slightly* more efficient :-)

Comment: I am. I think the solution is obvious

Comment: I would change your =='s to ==='s http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/

Comment: @JanDvorak It is.  I thought what you meant is to make one ternary expression.  I have always thought of ternary's as shorthand `if` statements.

Comment: @SethenMaleno you could write it with just one ternary, but it will be a mess

Comment: `max=(a>b)?(min=b,a):(min=a,b)`

Comment: @Jazzepi Funny that you bring that up.  There is much debate over the use of these two.  I have heard exactly the opposite from some developers I respect a lot.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ahh.  Very good.  Didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Jazzepi `undefined == null`, so `==` might be the correct one here

Comment: @SethenMaleno as I said, it's a mess. If someoneone used it in our codebase where `if` could have been used, I would get a huge `?` and bludgeon that guy.

Comment: @JanDvorak Haha, right on.  I can understand why.  Readability is non-existent at that point.

Comment: By the way, your code fails if both arrays are the same length.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm aware.  I will add that into the conditional.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're definitely correct. After some testing I've realized that you cannot pass an undeclared variable into a function  (an error will be thrown before the function begins to execute), but you CAN pass an undefined, but declared, variable into a function. So the == coerces the undefined to null and protects this function from operating on undefined functions.

Comment: @Jazzepi note that referencing a non-existent _property_ is not an error. `console.log(window.foo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to not use a ternary, and write a normal condition.

```
var bigArr, smallArr;
if(arrOne.length > arrTwo.length){
    bigArr = arrOne;
    smallArr = arrTwo;
}else{
    smallArr = arrOne;
    bigArr = arrTwo;
}
```

Readable, fast, it's obviously bug-free.

If you *really* want to use a ternary operator (for example to avoid duplicate declaration *and* assignment after declaration), perhaps the correct solution would be to repeat (or cache) the condition:

```
var   bigArr = arrOne.length > arrTwo.length ? arrOne.length : arrTwo.length,
    smallArr = arrOne.length > arrTwo.length ? arrTwo.length : arrOne.length;
```

Somewhat readable, obviously bug free, assigns at declaration.

If you want to avoid `if` *and* condition duplication, it's still possible. However, the code is unreadable (mainly because the comma operator is used) and shouldn't be used in production code. It might still be useful for code golf, though, and I'll name the variables appropriately. Handle with care:

```
l=(a.length>b.length)?(s=b,a):(s=a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail in cases where are there undefined values inbetween the array. If you need to handle such a condition, you might want to try a totally different approach.

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray[100] = true;
console.log(myArray.length); // returns 101
```